# online webex recording on ubuntu

Tags: webex

I've got problem with opening webex video on ubuntu-firefox. I need to open webex recording which was sent to me by email, having no permision to download it(to convert to mp4). I am able to connect webex test-meeting: java and libs seems to be ok.

I'm still getting 'set-up error' when trying to open video; with a message: "When a security message appears, click Yes to continue setting up WebEx Meeting Manager. If a security message does not appear or you clicked No, because you want to set up Meeting Manager at a later time, download the installer. Then start to manually install Meeting Manager..."

I don't find webex player for linux.

would be grateful for any help